# Is there a way to move the program counter in the Chrome debugger?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, program-counter

Is there a way to move the program counter to a given line when debugging Javascript in Chrome? I do not mean continue to a given line, but to skip instructions.

I wasn't able to find anything in the tutorials or help. I'm using v 49.0.2623.87 at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is not, but you can wrap all that code to be executed in a function and call it via console. Or just copy and paste the code you want it to be executed into the console... Try to find a solution this way. Hope it helps!

Comment: Hm. I suppose that's a decent workaround to refreshing the whole page. Thanks for the idea.